# IfNULL giving error

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the code I have.

```
SELECT CustNum, IFNULL(CustRep, 'None') AS CustRep
FROM Customers;
```

The Error I am getting is

> ORA-00904: "IFNULL": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 11 Column: 8

I understand the issue is with the IFNULL but I am unsure why.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about `IFNULL` but you can use `NVL` in your scenario :

```
SELECT CustNum, NVL(CustRep, 'None') AS CustRep
FROM Customers;
```

Comment: I am getting an invalid number error. CustRep is a char is there a way to work around that?

Comment: Can you change it to  NVL(TO_CHAR(CustRep), 'None')

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT CustNum, COALESCE(CustRep, 'None') AS CustRep
FROM Customers;
```

Comment: When I use COALESCE() It tells me it expects a Number. CustRep is a Char is there a way I can work around that?

Comment: `COALSCE()` works just fine on strings.  Are you sure that `CustRep` is a string?